# Is there a general term formula for 3 queens problem?

Tags: algorithm, math, permutation, n-queens

The specific question description is:
Put 3 queens on a chessboard of M columns and N rows, how to determine the number of ways that no two of them are in attacking positions?

Note that M is not equals to N, and M/N are larger than a `Integer` in C language so that there is no way to solve this question using classical computer algorithm like DFS/BFS(for time and memory complexity considerations).

I guess this problem can be calculated by the mathematical method of **permutation** or **combination**, but I am not good at math, so, please help me.

Comment: It will be a complicated and messy formula.  Taking into account symmetries would make it even harder. You could start with a `3xN` board and count the possibilities manually. Or write a program to find these solutions for small `N`. Once you have 4 or so non-zero solutions, you could try to see if you find a pattern or to look up the sequence in oeis.org Then you could start tackling `4xN` etc.

Comment: Just placing 3 rooks would be `(M*N)*((M-1)*(N-1))*((M-2)*(N-2))/3!`. From this number you should subtract all possibilities where 2 or 3 queens share the same upward or downward diagonal.

Comment: Thank you very much! I have worked in this problem for days, and I have tried to got the number of Rooks game then subtracted the number of situations of diagonals from the Rooks number. But, it is too complicated for me to find out every diagonals situations. So now I am desperate for a more clear way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes.**

Searching for keyword "3 queens" in OEIS gives us [A047659](https://oeis.org/A047659), and in the Formula section, Vaclav Kotesovec wrote that:

> In general, for m <= n, n >= 3, the number of ways to place 3 nonattacking queens on an m X n board is n^3/6*(m^3 - 3*m^2 + 2*m) - n^2/2*(3*m^3 - 9*m^2 + 6*m) + n/6*(2*m^4 + 20*m^3 - 77*m^2 + 58*m) - 1/24*(39*m^4 - 82*m^3 - 36*m^2 + 88*m) + 1/16*(2*m - 4*n + 1)*(1 + (-1)^(m+1)) + 1/2*(1 + abs(n - 2*m + 3) - abs(n - 2*m + 4))*(1/24*((n - 2*m + 11)^4 - 42*(n - 2*m + 11)^3 + 656*(n - 2*m + 11)^2 - 4518*(n - 2*m + 11) + 11583) - 1/16*(4*m - 2*n - 1)*(1 + (-1)^(n+1))) [Panos Louridas, idee & form 93/2007, pp. 2936-2938].

This formula can be manually confirmed on small Ns and Ms. A simple Python script for this purpose is shown below:

```py
import fractions # to avoid floating error
m = fractions.Fraction(4)
n = fractions.Fraction(4)
assert m<=n
one = fractions.Fraction(1) 
ans = n**3/6*(m**3 - 3*m**2 + 2*m) - n**2/2*(3*m**3 - 9*m**2 + 6*m) + n/6*(2*m**4 + 20*m**3 - 77*m**2 + 58*m) - one/24*(39*m**4 - 82*m**3 - 36*m**2 + 88*m) + one/16*(2*m - 4*n + 1)*(1 + (-1)**(m+1)) + one/2*(1 + abs(n - 2*m + 3) - abs(n - 2*m + 4))*(one/24*((n - 2*m + 11)**4 - 42*(n - 2*m + 11)**3 + 656*(n - 2*m + 11)**2 - 4518*(n - 2*m + 11) + 11583) - one/16*(4*m - 2*n - 1)*(1 + (-1)**(n+1)))
print(ans)
```

Unfortunately, I failed to find the proof of this formula (`[Panos Louridas, idee & form 93/2007, pp. 2936-2938]`, as Vaclav Kotesovec cited). [The journal *idee & form*](https://www.kunstschach.ch/idee_form.html) does not seem to be freely accessible. But due to the reputation of Vaclav Kotesovec (the author of [*Non-attacking chess pieces*](http://www.kotesovec.cz/books/kotesovec_non_attacking_chess_pieces_2013_6ed.pdf)), I think we should trust this result.

Comment: I can confirm the formula works for m and n up to the low hundreds, and it has the correct scaling behavior. It can also be simplified by replacing the abs() calls with a conditional. I didn't find this formula in *Non-attacking chess pieces*, but I suspect it must be derivable from simplifying an inclusion/exclusion sum.

Comment: @kcsquared *Non-attacking chess pieces* said in P11 that `Note: Panos Louridas published in Idea & Form 93/2007 (pp. 2936-2938) a more general formula for placing 3 ladies on a m x n board. However, the formula is quite inelegant (takes up almost half a page), so I am interested in this article` (translated to English). But the formula is not in this book.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is inclusion/exclusion.

We start by counting the number of ways to place 3 queens in order.  Which is just `(n*m) * (n*m - 1) * (n*m - 2)`.

Now we have overcounted, because we don't want the count of the number of ways  to place 3 queens with queens 1,2 attacking.  Or queens 1,3.  Or queens 2,3.  But that is just the sum over rows, columns and diagonals of length `l` of `l * (l-1) * (m*n-2)`.

But now we have undercounted, because if all 3 queens attack each other then we added them in the first step, subtracted 3x in the second step, and now we need to add them back 2x to get to counting those 0 times.  Which is the sum over rows, columns and diagonals of length `l` of `l * (l-1) * (l-2)`.

But this is the count of ways to place all of the queens in order.  But given 3 queens on the board, there are 6 orders we could place them.  So divide the whole answer by 6.

This can be turned into a program that is `O(n+m)` to run.  Which should be fast enough for your purposes.  If you were willing to do a bunch more analysis, we could actually produce a `O(1)` formula.

Comment: Thank you sincerely for your patient and professional answer! But, I can't figure out that `l` in your description. Could you please explain what does that `l` mean?

Comment: @Freya `l` means the `length` of the row, column, or diagonal along which the attack happens.  In a `5*9` board there will be `5` `9`'s for the columns, `9` `5`'s for the rows, and there will be `4` diagonals of lengths `1`, `2`, `3`, and `4`. then `10` diagonals of length `5`.  (Hope I counted right.)

Comment: I believe the final inclusion-exclusion term is not correct. `l*(l-1)*(l-2)` counts the ways for all three queens to attack each other *on the same row/col/diagonal*. But if you place them in a triangle, e.g. `(0,0), (0, 1), (1,0)`, they are still undercounted after the second term but not added back. There's also the case where only two pairs of queens are attacking each other instead of all 3.

Comment: kcsquared You are, sadly, absolutely correct. :-(

Answer (score -1):

The field with coordinates `(i, j)` is vulnerable for the queen locаted at `(qi , qj)` if

```
    i == qi || j == qj || abs(i - j) == abs(qi - qj)
```

This boolean expression should be `false` for feasible coordinates of each queen. Finding three such fields should not be hard. One cаn try Monte Carlo method which has complexity `o(M * N)` in worst case.

Comment: Thank you very much! I am writing a code now and I hope the I can get the result before the DDL.

Comment: Monte Carlo is never going to give anything other than an approximate answer about what proportion of ways to place the queens results in 2 attacking.  And for that approximation to accumulate to a precision where you can figure out an exact answer will take `O((n*m)^6)` - which is much worse than brute force.